# Algorithm to get N best-fit values based on succeed/failed count and succeed/failed dates

Tags: c#, algorithm, best-fit

I've got a list of proxy servers.
There is a list of `ProxyServer` items. Item holds proxy `Address` itself, `SucceedCount`, `FailedCount`, `LastSucceedDate`, `LastFailedDate`.
If loading operation succeed, `SucceedCount` is incremented, if failed - `FailedCount`.
So the items list looks like this (`LastFailedDate` is not presented):

[image]

I need to implement a simple algorithm to get N best proxy from this list.
Best proxy means:

- many `SucceedCount` is good
- many `FailedCount` is bad
- proxy with succeed/failed 0/0 is better than 0/10
- last success/failed date must have some weight, for example proxy with top `SucceedCount`/`FailedCount` 10000/100, but `LastSucceedDate` month ago counts as bad enough.

I hope you got the idea to get best N proxy for that moment. I guess there are some known algorithms for tasks like this. Looks like the algorithm itself can be something like `.OrderBy()` chain.

`SucceedCount`, `FailedCount`, `LastSucceedDate`, `LastFailedDate` fields ​​may be replaced by any others, deleted, or ​​may be supplemented by others, I just need the way to achieve the goal.

Comment: What is better: 1000/1 or 0/0 ?

Comment: 500/1 or 10/0? :)  What I want to say is that the problem with ranking is not the algorithm itself but rather what you consider to be an expected result. So, the first (and hardest) thing you want to do is to create solid set of test cases. After that almost every algorithm will work. If you decide to write algorithm by hand (should be easy in this case), I suggest using pairwise ranking: write comparator which accepts feature vectors for pair of proxy servers and returns boolean value which one is better. Otherwise look into [tag:machine-learning] to get info about advanced methods (e.g. SVM)

Comment: @gudok, Ok, thanks for your useful guidelines! I'll dive deeper.

Comment: You could look into the various approaches online news aggregators (reddit and the like) take with votes - map a `Succeed` to an upvote and a `Failed` to a downvote, and your 'Best proxy means' list looks a lot like reddit post ranking.